# Providing wind direction with wrf-python package

Tags: wind, python, wrf

I understand that wrf.getvar will give both the speed (dim 0) and the direction (dim 1)
V1 = wrf.getvar(ncdin, "uvmet10_wspd_wdir", units="m s-1",timeidx=wrf.ALL_TIMES,meta=False)[1,...]

But, I would like to ask about the way that direction is provided by the package. 0 degrees is wind from the north, 90 from the east etc?
For example if the output for dim 1 is 45 the wind is northestearn?

P.S. The link (https://wrf-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internal_api/generated/wrf.g_uvmet.get_uvmet10_wspd_wdir.html) may be useful.

Thanks,
Dimitris